# EULAs and Remote Support Policies

Tags: untagged

This question arose because I recently allowed a support technician help me with an problem with an installation of a software product on my computer.  The support technician took remote control over my machine and proceeded to install the software, even agreeing to the EULA.  I specifically asked him if he needed me to approve the EULA agreement, but he said he would do that himself.

This made me start to wonder if I would now be bound by the conditions of the EULA since I did not physically agree to them.

So - that said my question is - if you or your company provide remote technical support:

1) Do you have a policy of how technicians should handle EULA agreement dialogs while they are in control of a customer/client's computer?

2) Do you have a statement in your "terms of use" for remote support that covers these types of scenarios?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 1):

EULAs in installation programs are already legally dubious.

I would expect that since they are working on your behalf that they can agree to it on your behalf.  Although as a technician I would probably cover myself by making sure that the customer had at least seen it.

But since this is a legal issue, not a technical one, you should really be seeking advice from a qualified legal professional rather than here.

Comment: Understood - I'm not really looking for the legal answer - I am more interested in whether organizations have policies on this or have terms in their remote assistance terms of use.